# Power BI Report Server RLS

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular, power-bi-report-server, row-level-security

I have a SSAS Tabular model which connects live to Power BI. RLS is implemented at the model level. Is there a way to implement RLS on certain tabs of the dashboard only. For e.g. if there are five tabs in a dashboard, can RLS be disabled for two and enabled on the remaining of them. Also, is there a way to disable RLS at dax or measure level? Any information will be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

RLS is for security, not filtering. If you can turn off security and it's not a problem, then just turn off security. If you think you're able to turn off security on certain tabs because the data is aggregated, think again. That's not how security works. The user will have a way to get at row level data through some means of drill down or filtering or Q+A or data download that you aren't aware of, so just don't do it. If aggregated data is ok, build an aggregation table and use that on the other tabs, but leave RLS on if you need to secure the data.

Comment: the whole point of this exercise is to have one dashboard in which all users can see the benchmark data on one tab and as they switch to other tabs, data relevant to their location is only visible.

Comment: But are you securing data or filtering data? Securing the data means they are not allowed to ever see other locations' data. Filtering means they are allowed to see other locations, but you have hidden them through a filter. If they are allowed to see all the other user's data, just use filters. You can setup filters off of USERPRINCIPALNAME( ) even if you aren't using RLS.

Comment: I am securing data so that they can see high level information but not detailed level